# Настроить jarsigner-plugin

Tags: maven, applet, jar, сертификат

Могу подписать созданный jar командой jarsigned, значит хранилище и сертификат в порядке. Но когда пытаюсь сделать то же самое с помощью maven, получаю LifecycleExecutionException при работе maven-jarsigner-plugin. Вот плагины в pom:

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>

<plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.5</source>
<target>1.5</target>
<optimize>true</optimize>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
<descriptors>
<descriptor>src/assemble/assemble.xml</descriptor>
</descriptors>
<archive>
<manifest>
<mainClass>com.MyApplet.Applet</mainClass>
</manifest>
<manifestEntries>
<Application-Name>MyApplet</Application-Name>
<Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions>
<Codebase>*</Codebase>
</manifestEntries>
</archive>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>my-assembly</id>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>assembly</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<archive>
<addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
<manifestEntries>
<Application-Name>MyApplet</Application-Name>
<Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library>
<Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions>
<Codebase>*</Codebase>
</manifestEntries>
</archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>sign</id>
<phase>install</phase>
<goals>
<goal>sign</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<archiveDirectory>target</archiveDirectory>
<includes>
<include>**/*with-dependencies.jar</include>
</includes>
<keystore>certificate/MySite.jks</keystore>
<alias>server</alias>
<storepass>123456</storepass>
<keypass>123456</keypass>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Что здесь не так?
В инете поискала, нашла [вот это](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SM/LifecycleExecutionException+-+The+service+unit+xyz+does+not+have+a+dependency+which+is+packaged+as+a+jbi-component). Но не помогает.

**Обновление**

Да, пробовала сделать то же самое вручную, вызвать jarsigner-plugin из командной строки для полученного jar, результат тот же. Падает с той же ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашла решение сама:

http://iliachemodanov.ru/ru/blog-ru/14-tools/maven/43-maven-assembly-plugin-bug-ru

Первое решение сработало у меня, второе дает такую же ошибку.